# Convert the EL functions represented version in the pom to the ACTUAL values maintained in properties tag

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, el

I have a problem when using xpp3 to get the version of an artifact when the version is maintained in  tag. 
I used the `org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader` to get the model, then get the Properties

```
MavenXpp3Reader pomReader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(pom);
model = pomReader.read(fileReader);

//e.g. ${rsfutil.version}-sakai_${sakairsf.sakai.version}
String version = pomModel.getVersion();

Properties properties = pomModel.getProperties();
Enumeration<?> enumeration = properties.propertyNames();

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()){
     Object o = enumeration.nextElement();
     list.add((String)o);
}


for (String string : list) {
    if (version.contains(string)){
       String property = properties.getProperty(string);
       version = version.replace(Pattern.quote("${"+string+"}"), property);
    }
}
System.out.println(version);
```

Even the regex matched, the replace method still doesn't work.

And the pom is like this:

```
  <artifactId>SakaiRSFComponents-evolvers</artifactId>
  <parent>
    <groupId>uk.org.ponder.pure-poms</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard-sakai-tool</artifactId>
    <version>POM-4</version>
  </parent>
  <name>Sakai RSF Components Evolvers</name>
  <groupId>uk.org.ponder.sakairsf</groupId>
  <properties>
    <sakairsf.sakai.version>2.2.x</sakairsf.sakai.version>
    <rsfutil.version>0.7.4</rsfutil.version>
    <ponderutilcore.version>1.2.4</ponderutilcore.version>
    <jservletutil.version>1.2.4</jservletutil.version>
    <sakai.version>[2.2.0,2.7.0)</sakai.version>
  </properties>
  <version>${rsfutil.version}-sakai_${sakairsf.sakai.version}</version>
...
```

All I want to do is getting the actual version `0.7.4-sakai_2.2.x` instead of `${rsfutil.version}-sakai_${sakairsf.sakai.version}` .

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found that I should use the replaceAll method instead of replace method.